# How to flush Couchbase bucket from Java code?

Tags: java, couchbase

I need to clear a Couchbase bucket each time before unit test runs. I use the Java SDK > 2.0 version. In previous versions I found this wonderful method http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-java-client-1.1.1/com/couchbase/client/ClusterManager.html#flushBucket(java.lang.String) but it does not exist in new version.

Is there some way to clear data from bucket? I could delete by fetching all keys of documents and then delete them all, but I want to use more pretty way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually in the 2.x SDK you can get a `BucketManager` out of a `Bucket` instance, which will allow you to call `flush()` as wonderfully as before ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mind that it might be risky to flush and use N1QL queries afterwards in Community v4.0. My integration tests were failing because some documents didn't get indexed after a few dozens of runs (even after 30 minutes). It's safer to just delete documents.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the REST API to delete the bucket:
http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-bucket-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

In the [Couchbase Java 2.x SDK API Reference](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.1.4/) look at [BucketFlusher](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.1.4/com/couchbase/client/java/bucket/BucketFlusher.html).

Answer (score 0):

With Couchbase Java SDK 3.x:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.connect(connectionString, username, password);
cluster.buckets().flushBucket(bucketName);
```